# Kill all jobs spawned by sem

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..3}; do
    sem --no-notice --id $$ -j+0 sleep 10 ";" echo Done
done

sem --no-notice --id $$ --wait
```

Launch it, then how to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to terminate all the sleeps?

Comment: See if you can rewrite your code to use parallel in its normal mode instead. Then it works out of the box. (And consider running --bibtex just once).

Answer (score 2):

You could use traps to catch your `SIGINT` signal and manually kill all the processes spawned by your semaphores. Have a look at the following script :

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob #safety needed so that globs return empty strings when no files are present
trap kill_sem INT

function kill_sem() {
        for s in ~/.parallel/semaphores/id-$$/*@*;
        do
                kill -15 -- -$(basename ${s%%@*})
        done
}

for i in {1..3}; do
    sem --no-notice --id $$ -j+0 sleep 45 ";" echo Done
done

sem --no-notice --id $$ --wait
```

**Explanation :**

- `trap kill_sem INT` : Acts somewhat similarily to `try ... catch` blocks in other languages, but with signals rather than exception. Here, it waits for the `INT` signal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and executes the `kill_sem` function when this happens. [Link to trap documentation](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html).
- When you create a semaphore with `sem`, it will create a file using the following naming pattern: `~/.parallel/semaphore/id-MYSCRIPT_PID/SEM_PID@HOST`

  - `$(basename ${s%%@*})` : extracts the `SEM_PID` from all of those files, and use it as the `PID_GROUP` in the kill command
  - `kill -15 -- -PID_GROUP` : sends the `SIGTERM` signal to all processes belonging to the group `PID_GROUP`